# php for nested loop and if not working

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I try to make a simple program. to show a result for ex : if the array only contains a the `$result` will be "a" , if b the `$result` will be "b", if a & b then "ab"  etc. in this case the array contains a, b, and c and for some reason when I run it only shows "c".
here's my code :

```
$a[0] = "b";
$a[1] = "a";
$a[2] = "c";
for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($a); $j++) {
    for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($a); $k++) {
        for ($l=0; $l<sizeof($a); $l++) {
            if ($a[$j] == "a"){
                $result="a";
            }
            elseif ($a[$j] == "b") {
                $result="b";
            }
            elseif ($a[$j] == "c") {
                $result="c";
            }
            elseif ($a[$j] == "a" and $a[$k] == "b") {
                $result="ab";
            }
            elseif ($a[$j] == "c" and $a[$k] == "b" and $a[$l] == "a") {
                $result="abc";
            }
            elseif ($a[$j] == "b" and $a[$k] == "c") {
                $result="bc";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo ($result);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are looping three times?

Comment: if you have 3 nested loops, it means you are doing something wrong

Comment: It is only echoing `c`, as you are overwriting `$result` on each loop  iteration, so it will only echo the last setting of `$result`. You can see the behavior by changing all your `$result = ` to `$result .=` and you will see that your current code produces - `bbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaccccccccc`

Comment: Do they have to be in alphabetical order ?

Comment: Why not something like `sort($a); array_unique($a); echo implode("", $a);` ?

Comment: @garethl ... that is my questions as well

Comment: what do you try to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one loop and three flags. Try something like this

```
$a[0] = "b";
$a[1] = "a";
$a[2] = "c";
$hasA = false;
$hasB = false;
$hasC = false;
for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($a); $j++) {
    if ($a[$j] == "a"){
        $hasA = true;
    }
    elseif ($a[$j] == "b"){
        $hasB = true;
    }
    elseif ($a[$j] == "c"){
        $hasC = true;
    }
}
if ($hasA) echo 'a';
if ($hasB) echo 'b';
if ($hasC) echo 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all those loops aren't really necessary.

Use php switches.

```
 switch($value){
   case "a":
     // Actions here
   case "b": 
     // Actions here
 }
```

What you are doing in those for loops is keep overriding $result with a new value.
In the end it shows the last letter it found.

Aside from the fact, what purpose this code has. Try to look for a php debugger I would recommend using Xdebug.

A debugger helps a programmer detect problems by stepping into the code line by line and showing the state of every variable.

A good tutorial and development environnement tutorial is found [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simpler way to achieve this:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$result = '';
if(in_array('a', $a)){
$result .= 'a';
}
if(in_array('b', $a)){
$result .= 'b';
}
if(in_array('c', $a)){
$result .= 'c';
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: it only shows "a". I mean if my array contains "a, b, and c" the result will be "abc" like those in my codes. if there are only "a,b" in my array it will only shows "ab"

Comment: remove else for your statements

Comment: @botanbutton sorry i fixed it, this will avoid loops

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a different approach:

```
$array="asdasd";
$check=$arry[0];

$all_the_same=true;

for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++){
    if(array[$i] !== $check){
        $all_the_same=false;
        break;
    }
}
```

What I've done is to check all letters in the array to see if they're all the same, and set `$all_the_same` to false if they're not. To find out if the array has the letter you want:

```
if($check==="a")
     echo "has 'a'";
```

or perhaps the more civilized `switch / case` statement.

The problem with your code is that you run three loops over *the same data*. `$j` changes very slowly (every `sizeof($a)` squared to be precise) and it's the first thing you check so it's no surprise it always shows "c".

Answer (score 0):

```
$a[0] = "b";
$a[1] = "a";
$a[2] = "c";
$result = '';
foreach($a as $value) {
    if($value == 'a')
        $result .= 'a';
    if($value == 'b')
        $result .= 'b';
    if($value == 'c')
        $result .= 'c';
}

echo $result;
```

Here is a smoother version of what you tried to do!

Answer (score 0):

```
sort($array);
implode( array_unique(  $array ) );
```

As @GarethL had mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For the intention of the question, may meet this simple code

```
<?php
$a[0] = "b";
$a[1] = "a";
$a[2] = "c";
$result = implode($a);
echo $result;
```